# Change content for Material Design's responsive button based on screen's resolution

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I'm using Angular `8.x` along with Material Design components (for Angular) and `@angular/flex-layout@8.0.0-beta.26`.

I'm trying to make a responsive `mat-toolbar` and I'm running into a small issue (that I bet it's trivial for experienced folks) while *changing a `mat-button` component's content based on the screen size*.

This is my first approach:

```html
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="profileMenu" fxShow mat-button>
  <!-- Show this set when fxShow.gt-sm -->
  <mat-icon class="nav-link-icon" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>person</mat-icon>
  <span fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>{{ profile }}</span>
  <mat-icon fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>

  <!-- ...alternatively, show this set when fxShow.lt-md -->
  <mat-icon fxHide fxShow.lt-md>menu</mat-icon>
</button>
```

I thought I could wrap those elements in a `<div>` or something, but the positioning gets borked and I would have to account for those little tiny alignments. Additionally, there are some warnings that some elements are not allowed inside `<button>` following this approach.

I can have two `<button>` elements with the `Flex` settings applied to them once, but I'm not sure about this approach.

Finally, I was trying to make this work by using `ng-template` (I guess this is the best option, in my opinion; I was following [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview/)), but I couldn't find a way to do it:

```html
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="profileMenu" mat-button>
  <ng-template fxHide fxShow.gt-sm matMenuContent>
    <mat-icon class="nav-link-icon">person</mat-icon>
    <span>{{ profile }}</span>
    <mat-icon>arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template fxHide fxShow.lt-md matMenuContent>
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
</button>
```

Is it possible to use `ng-template` for this case. If so, any tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Angular my advice would be to make 2 buttons and use *ngif to trigger each one based on the screen size.

So in your .ts file load the screen size into a variable 'screenSize'.

And an example of your buttons using *ngif:

```
<button *ngIf="screenSize <= 1000" [matMenuTriggerFor]="profileMenu" fxShow mat-button>
  <!-- Show this set when fxShow.gt-sm -->
  <mat-icon class="nav-link-icon" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>person</mat-icon>
  <span fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>{{ profile }}</span>
  <mat-icon fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>

  <!-- ...alternatively, show this set when fxShow.lt-md -->
  <mat-icon fxHide fxShow.lt-md>menu</mat-icon>
</button>

<button *ngIf="screenSize > 1000" [matMenuTriggerFor]="profileMenu" fxShow mat-button>
  <!-- Show this set when fxShow.gt-sm -->
  <mat-icon class="nav-link-icon" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>person</mat-icon>
  <span fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>{{ profile }}</span>
  <mat-icon fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>

  <!-- ...alternatively, show this set when fxShow.lt-md -->
  <mat-icon fxHide fxShow.lt-md>menu</mat-icon>
</button>
```

So the first button will only appear when the screen size is 1000 or below.
The second button with different content will only appear when it is over 1000.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I know I can achieve this with two `<button>` elements, but I would like to do it with only one (as container), and changing the content inside. Probably it's OK, to have two `<button>` elements, but that feels odd for me.

Comment: Could you apply the *ngif approach to just the content within the button? Same concept but applied to the mat-icon and span elements.

Comment: I can do that, but somehow, if I put an element, say a `<div>`, `<span>`, or something else to wrap those sets and apply the `flex` settings once, I lose the margin/padding settings due to some other elements. That would have been perfect. It's the most intuitive approach IMO. Basically, I'm struggling to find a way to say: `if fxShow.gt-sm = true` show `this`, else `that`...inside an element, that's why I was trying to use `ng-template`.

Comment: Hmmm. I see what you're saying. The solution you are trying to go for seems to be the most elegant way. Can't see why it's not working with your approach. 

Looking at the flex API at https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxShow-API you might need to use the fx keywords like
`<div fxShow.sm="false"  fxShow.gt-md="false" fxShow="true" ></div>` 
on each element

Comment: So for your code:

`<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="profileMenu" fxShow mat-button>
  <!-- Show this set when fxShow.gt-sm -->
  <mat-icon class="nav-link-icon" fxHide="true" fxShow.gt-sm="true">person</mat-icon>
  <span fxHide="true" fxShow.gt-sm="true">{{ profile }}</span>
  <mat-icon fxHide="true" fxShow.gt-sm="true">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>

  <!-- ...alternatively, show this set when fxShow.lt-md -->
  <mat-icon fxHide="true" fxShow.lt-md="true">menu</mat-icon>
</button>`

Comment: Oh, it works, I was just trying to see there was a better way; in the end, I went with the two `<button>` elements approach. Looks like it's fine to "hide" elements and that sort of stuff, as long as they don't use _much_ resources, etc. Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working in the end. Would you mind accepting the answer to the post?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to apply the responsive classes to the button elements themselves. Check out this [stackblitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-responsive-buttons)

```
<button mat-button mat-icon-button fxHide fxShow.gt-sm  [matMenuTriggerFor]="profileMenu">
  <mat-icon class="nav-link-icon">person</mat-icon>
  <span>{{ profile }}</span>
  <mat-icon>arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
</button>
<button mat-button fxHide fxShow.lt-md [matMenuTriggerFor]="profileMenu">
   <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon> 
</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I can achieve this with two `<button>` elements, but I would like to do it with only one (as container), and changing the content inside. Probably it's OK, to have two `<button>` elements, but that feels odd for me.